# File operations JNI

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm new to android and JNI. I want to access files in the device. I've added permissions to the Manifest yet it doesn't work.

The Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
public native String  setFilePath(String path);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    TextView  tv = new TextView(this);

    tv.setText( "1111" );


    setContentView(tv);
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/xyz"; 
    Log.i("java ", path);
    setFilePath(path);

}
}
```

The C code:

```
jint Java_package_MainActivity_setFilePath(JNIEnv* env, jobject this,jstring Path){



path = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars( env, Path , NULL ) ;
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "SO", "fopen(%s)", path);
FILE* file = fopen(path,"ab+");
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars( env, Path , path );
fputs("Testing!\n", file);
fclose(file);
return 0;
}
```

An error comes up as:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000c (code=1), thread 16152
```

Comment: i guess its an issue related to memory usage.Have you searched it?

Comment: fopen() takes a const char *, ie a C-style null terminated string rather than a jstring.  Use GetStringUTFChars().

Comment: @AnirudhSharma I looked everywhere. I did read somewhere that it could be a possibility that one of the variables are null. But I'm not able to confirm that because this error comes up even when I try to print it on the console

Comment: have you checked @ChrisStratton comment

Comment: Oh yes. I did. No luck :(

Comment: Edit your post to include the native stack trace.

Comment: And of course this is not going to work when you obtain a char * but continue erroneously passing the jstring rather than the char * to fopen().

Comment: Where's the Java declaration of `setFilePath()`?

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake there. Check Edited post.

Comment: Well your native C class declaration isn't correct. The second parameter is a `jclass` if the method is static.

Comment: I tried both with and without static (adding the jclass). The error still persists

Comment: I am able to pass the string to the c file. But the fopen always returns nulll even though there's a file of that name in the exact location. When I cat the file on adb shell it is read properly.

Comment: If `fopen()` returns null there *isn't* a file in that location, or you don't have access to it. You need to program more defensively, instead of assuming that all operations just succeed. And your C method declaration still needs to agree with your Java native declaration.

Comment: Is there any reason why I can't access it ? Should the device be rooted ?

Comment: Maybe it's just permission issue as stated in my answer.

Comment: I had set up all the permissions already in the manifest(read and write )

Answer (score 0):

```
// Path is an jstring passed as an arg of a function
char *path = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars( env, Path , NULL ) ;
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "SO", "fopen(%s)", path);
FILE* file = fopen(path,"ab+");
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars( env, Path , path );
fputs("Testing!\n", file);
fclose(file);
```

If it does not work, post what is printed to logcat.

Comment: Tried exactly what you suggested. Its the same Fatal signal error. The log doesn't show up too.

Comment: "The log doesn't show up" - even `Log.i("java ", path)`? BTW, does your Java file start with `package package.MainActivity`?

Comment: I'm sorry, When I said log I meant the _android_log_print . But that's working now. because I had placed it after the File operations, It wasn't executed. It's the file operation open that will always return null.

Comment: Check if you can write to this file in Java, that will resolve the permissions doubt.

Comment: I could write the file in Java. So I guess it's not a permission problem

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking the result of any of those calls. JNi programing needs extreme defence, and `fopen()` can return null as well.

It's hard to see why you're using `fopen()` or indeed JNI at all, when it could all be done in Java.

Comment: I have to use ffmpeg in JNI. So I need to access the files in the JNI itself.